# transformation along the y axis is varying in iphone4 and iphone 6, CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am using CABasicAnimation to move a picture along the y axis by following

```
CABasicAnimation   *translationY    =   [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
translationY.fromValue              =   [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
translationY.toValue                =   [NSNumber numberWithInt:-150];
translationY.duration               =   1;
translationY.delegate               =   self;
translationY.removedOnCompletion    =   NO;
translationY.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[self.logo.layer addAnimation:translationY forKey:nil];
```

However when I am testing on the device ( iphone4 and iphone5 ), the `toValue` is performed differently.

Pictures are attached below

iphone 5:

[image]

and iphone4:
[image]

How can we make sure transformation along y axis is the same for ip4 and ip5

Comment: There's an iPhone 6 already?  I can't keep up...

Comment: That animation should be the same for both. Are you sure the positions are what you expect them without the animation? the transform isn't used elsewhere, right?

Comment: iam positive about that and transformation is not used elsewhere